# How do I get a is_safe_url() function to use with Flask and how does it work?

Tags: python, security, flask

Flask-Login recommends having an is_safe_url() function after user login:

Here is a link to the part of the documentation that discusses this:
https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example

They link to this snippet but I don't understand how it implements `is_safe_url()`:
https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/

```
next = request.args.get('next')
if not is_safe_url(next):
     return abort(400)
```

This doesn't seem to come with Flask. I'm relatively new to coding. I want to understand:

- What exactly is happening when `request` gets the `next` argument?
- What does the `is_safe_url()` function do to ensure the URL is safe?
- Does the next URL need to be checked on login only? Or are there other places and times when it is important to include this security measure?
- And most importantly: is there a reliable `is_safe_url()` function that I can use with Flask?

Edit: Added link to Flask-Login documentation and included snippet.

Comment: Yeah, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: The next line in the docs after the code example: _Warning: You MUST validate the value of the next parameter. If you do not, your application will be vulnerable to open redirects. For an example implementation of is_safe_url see [this Flask Snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/62/)._

Comment: @PeterCharland _Yeah, is there a better way to do that?_ I fixed it, the dashes were on the empty lines, instead of in front of the text.

Comment: @AMC - oh OK, weird, I moved the dashes down because it wasn't showing up the way I had it.

Comment: @AMC - yeah, I saw that line, but I don't understand how it's relevant. The linked snippet doesn't seem to be addressing the safety of a URL at all.

Comment: _I moved the dashes down because it wasn't showing up the way I had it._ Wasn't that the issue in the first place?

Comment: @AMC Nevermind, the formatting is fine now.

Comment: @PeterCharland Weren't you trying to make a list using the dashes?

Comment: Yeah, someone else edited and took them out, looks like. Honestly I don't really care either way. edit: @AMC

Comment: @PeterCharland They removed them because it looks like you undid the list formatting after my edit, so it was back to the huge bold text.

Comment: @AMC gotcha, sorry--I was doing a text edit and I loaded it before your edit, but saved it after, so it overwrote yours. If you want to edit it again that would be cool or you could tell me how to do it. Either way ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks :) Now I just need an answer to my question... lol

Comment: @PeterCharland You probably figured this out already, but the link on Flask-Login page appears to be broken, it redirects to the front page of Flask project. Here is the snippet from internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20190128010142/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/62/

Comment: @EmrahDiril Aha!--I in fact did not notice that.

Comment: In fact, the link seems broken.
I think the actual working URL is here : https://github.com/fengsp/flask-snippets/blob/master/security/redirect_back.py

Comment: Yep, thanks! The last comment had directed me to a similar snippet. Thanks for sharing that one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Flask-Login today had a dead link in the documentation ([issue](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/490) on GitHub). Please note the warning in the original flask snippets documentation:

> Snippets are unofficial and unmaintained. No Flask maintainer has curated or checked the snippets for security, correctness, or design.

The snippet is

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin

def is_safe_url(target):
    ref_url = urlparse(request.host_url)
    test_url = urlparse(urljoin(request.host_url, target))
    return test_url.scheme in ('http', 'https') and \
           ref_url.netloc == test_url.netloc
```

Now to address your questions:

> What exactly is happening when request gets the next argument?

Part of the code we are focusing on here is

```py
next = request.args.get('next')
return redirect(next or url_for('dashboard'))
```

which redirects user to dashboard (e.g. after successful login) by default. However, if user tried to reach for e.g. endpoint `profile` and wasn't logged in we would want to redirect him to the login page. After logging in default redirect would redirect user to `dashboard` and not to `profile` where he intended to go. To provide better user experience we can redirect user to his profile page by [building URL](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building) `/login?next=profile`, which enables flask to redirect to `profile` instead of the default `dashboard`.

Since user can abuse URLs we want to check if URL is safe, or abort otherwise.

> What does the is_safe_url() function do to ensure the URL is safe?

The snippet in question is a function that ensures that a redirect target will lead to the same server.

> Does the next URL need to be checked on login only? Or are there other places and times when it is important to include this security measure?

No, you should check all dangerous URLs. Example of safe URL redirect would be `redirect(url_for('index'))`, since its hardcoded in your program. See examples of safe and dangerous URLs on [Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards - OWASP cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet.html).

> And most importantly: is there a reliable is_safe_url() function that I can use with Flask?

There is Django's is_safe_url() bundled as a standalone package on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/is-safe-url/).

Comment: OK, great. I believe I understand: so Flask-Login has a built-in `next` parameter that it references when redirecting with `@login_required`. In order to use this feature safely, I first need to ensure that the URL resulting from that next parameter is both using a safe (http/https) protocol and that it does not redirect to a different site. Thank you! Let me know if I missed anything with that.

Comment: `next = request.args.get('next')`, next isn't built in, we got it from request.args, and we can use it to send user to the `?next=` specified in the URL, independent of Flask-Login

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer covers the theory well. Here is one way to deploy a 'safe URL' strategy throughout your Flask project, involving no additional libraries:

util.py:

```
def is_safe_url(target):
    ref_url = urlparse(request.host_url)
    test_url = urlparse(urljoin(request.host_url, target))
    return test_url.scheme in ('http', 'https') and ref_url.netloc == test_url.netloc


def get_redirect_target():
    for target in request.values.get('next'), request.args.get('next'):
        if not target:
            continue
        if is_safe_url(target):
            return target


def redirect_back(endpoint, **values):
    target = request.form['next'] if request.form and 'next' in request.form else request.args.get('next')
    if not target or not is_safe_url(target):
        target = url_for(endpoint, **values)
    return redirect(target)
```

example routes.py (one of many):

```
from util import get_redirect_target, redirect_back

@bp.route('/routepath', methods=['GET', 'POST'], strict_slashes=False)
@login_required
def my_route():
    # use these styles (both or separately) as needed

    if not (some_condition):
        return redirect_back('someother_route')

    return_url = get_redirect_target() or url_for('another_route')
    ...
    return redirect(return_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

`is_safe_url` is a python module.
Your code is ok just import after you install the module:

```
#install:
python3 -m pip install is_safe_url
```

```
#import:
from is_safe_url import is_safe_url
```

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446498/5320906) already mentions this package.  This answer does not add any additional value.